Cannot publish whole collaboration branch to data factory live mode
We have setup azure devops in Azure data factory. My colloboration branch (lets call it master) has more than 200 pipelines and more than 40o datasets. I changed the colloboration branch to a newly created branch based on azure publish branch and i noticed next day that there is no content in my live mode. It basically synced with the new colloboration branch. My master still holds all the pipelines and datasets we had.
Now when i changed the colloboration branch to Master branch again and tried publishing hoping i would get my live mode synced with master again. It did not work, i get an error


Now i cannot publish datasets, pipelines independently as they have
dependancies and i get validation error.
I also cannot spend time to create logical group of supporting
artifacts and publish individual projects as there are a lot of
them.
I also tried overwrite collaboration branch to live mode but i end
up with the same error.
I also tried creating one more adf instance and publish there just
for the sake but it did not work.

I am out of options and need help as none of my 198 pipelines are running as only the pipelines in live mode run via triggers. i cannot manually run 198 pipelines.
Thanks and appreciate your help.
